# Add two list to Response using Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Sorry by the question but I'm really new using Spring Boot. My problem is the following.
We have an endpoint with this kind of response:

```
[
    "The order number 1 was success",
    "The order number 2 was success",
    "The order number 3 was success",
    "The order number 4 failed",
]
```

The response is a List. I need modify this endpoint to get a response like

```
{
   "errors":[
      "The order number 4 failed"
   ],
   "successful":[
      "The order number 1 was success",
      "The order number 2 was success",
      "The order number 3 was success",
   ]
}
```

Can you give me any clou how can I return two different list? Or what I need modify to get that response

Thanks.

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: Please share with us the code in the endpoint and the code you've tried to get your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a POJO (Java Class) with two variable fields which are the two lists. Ensure that you have getters and setters. Then you can return that object, rather than list(s) directly

```
public class TwoLists {

private List<String> errors;
private List<String> successful; // add getters and setters }
```

return ResponseEntity< TwoLists > from your end point.